# Reduce output of curl command

Tags: bash, shell, curl

When I run a curl command against my non-running server, I get below output.

I only want

> Failed to connect: Connection Refused

How can I remove the extra output. If I run `--silent`, it suppress everything.

---

I get this o/p for `curl http://localhost:300/index.html`

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  9626  100  9626    0     0   148k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  149k
Failed to connect: Connection Refused
```

Comment: Looks like I need to use -sS

Comment: Post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! using `-s`, `--silent`  along with  `-S`, `--show-error` is the right option.

Answer (score 1):

Curl gives me the compressed output by default, but try:

```
curl --compressed http://localhost:300/index.html
```

By contrast `--verbose` returns more lengthy output.

`man curl` will show you all the options available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I need to use -sS. man curl will show you all the options available to you.